# Destroy just the inner DOM of an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, noble-count

I have implemented a counter using [NobleCount](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/NobleCount) like this:

```
$('#message').NobleCount('#messageInfo',{
    max_chars: max,
    block_negative: true
});
```

For some reason I need to update the counter. But it does not help to just call the code above to update the counter.

So I thought to remove all DOM from the **#messageInfo** box. But `remove()` removes the #messageInfo element itself too.

Any idea how to remove just the inner DOM of #messageInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) -

```
$('#message').empty();
```